# Create a shorcut to a specific FTP folder in Windows on the Desktop and the Taskbar?

Tags: windows, ftp, shortcuts

Is it possible to create a shortcut to a specific FTP folder in Windows?

I have already added my FTP site by using

**My Computer > Add Network Location > FTP Address**.

However, explorer opens up my default folder. I have to frequently access a specific folder which is located at:

**Home > public_html > assets > images > platform > products**

Can I create a shortcut, which will launch the **products** folder directly?

**EDIT:** To make it easy to understand - I'd like to have a shortcut to the FTP sub-folder on the Desktop and be able to pin it to the Taskbar (essential)

Comment: I find your question confusing: do you want to access your `...\products` folder through FTP, or do you want direct file access to the files handled by your FTP server? In the first case a network location works fine in Windows 10; in the second case you can use a symbolic link in any convenient location, such as your home directory.

Comment: It's the former. To make it clear - an explorer shorcut that can pinned to the Start Screen and the taskbar (essential).

Comment: In that case Andre's answer should work, but you will need to add `explorer` to the short-cut, as in `explorer ftp://...`; otherwise the short-cut will open the site in a browser, not Windows Explorer.

Comment: @AFH Thank you! That worked! If you can properly form your comment to include Andre's answer along with the steps to make a shortcut for a desktop and pin it to taskbar, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a short-cut on your desk-top and for the location of the item enter:

```
explorer ftp://username:password@ftpserver.com/public_html/assets/images/platform/products
```

(This is the same answer as Andre gave, but with the addition of `explorer` to stop the FTP site opening in a browser.)

You can then right-click on the short-cut and select `Pin to taskbar`.

Note that navigating upwards will work up the directory tree, whereas using a network location will go straight from the FTP site to `My Computer` (or `This PC` on Windows 10).

Comment: On Windows 7 it says that explorer.exe has changed or moved: https://i.imgur.com/eq1CJtv.png

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi - I don't understand this: is there something missing from your `PATH`? What does `where explorer` show in `cmd`? It should be in the Windows directory (`%windir%`). You can always add the directory path to `explorer` in the shortcut.

Comment: Got it working but for example if I want to save from browser something directly to FTP then I can't click on that shortcut to FTP.

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi - You can't use the shortcut as a copy target: you need to open the shortcut and paste into the explorer window.

Comment: What if the password contains an @ character?

Answer (score 1):

You can also map it directly to the products folder by entering:
`ftp://username:password@ftpserver.com/public_html/assets/images/platform/products`

Comment: Have you tried this personally? Because Windows won't let me do it. It says "Windows cannot access the folder". I have been scratching my head and I'm pretty confident that I have tried almost everything including direct mapping to the folder. :(

Comment: Indeed I have used that already, yes. Can you share your exact url? (obviously without your credentials) Maybe we can find something out.

Comment: I have tried this - ftp://username:password@ftp.buyonlinecheap.co.uk/public_html/assets/images/eBay%20Desc/products/

Comment: Can you try to add this until the ebay part? ftp://username:password@ftp.buyonlinecheap.co.uk/public_html/assets/images/ I think that Windows probably has issues with the %20 / blank space at the ebay part.

Comment: I'm sorry it did work! Actually, I was trying to put that in something else. But now, I have a problem. This is an internet shortcut. How can I open this in "explorer"?

Comment: Try to open the ftp in your internet explorer. Press `ALT` to show the menu bar and click on `View`. Now choose `Open FTP Site in File Explorer`

Comment: But then would I have to do this everytime?

Comment: I think it's remembering that. But you'd have to try that.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a shortcut to IE `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` and open the properies and add your FTP side: `"ftp://username:password@ftpserver.com/public_html/assets/images/platform/products"` ?

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just try to make it with a simple way? i.e. in Desktop context menu choose New >> Shortcut then write your specific FTP adrress in the first textbox that appears there? [Sorry for my bad English]

Comment: Welcome to SU, IMO when you post an answer you should make it look as an answer, an answer can't be answered with question, if you have questions, do comments, if you have not enough rep we have a complete model describing how it works http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Ghost86 Have you tried that personally? It becomes an "Internet shortcut". I'd like to open it in "EXPLORER"